# How to change content TabViewItem? UWP XAML WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, uwp

I have a TabView element. My task is to change the content of a tab to a Webview. Initially, a Page is installed there as the content. After changing the content of the TabViewItem, the WebView element is not displayed, and appears only after switching tabs. How can I make it so that after changing the Content property, the WebView element immediately starts to be displayed, and not just after switching tabs?[image: There is a click on the GridView element and the page starts loading, but the WebView is not displayed][image: I switched between tabs and now the content is displayed as expected]

```
public void SearchWebFromStartPage(string url)
        {

            var newWebView = new WebView(WebViewExecutionMode.SeparateProcess);
            WebViewStates.Add(newWebView, true);
            newWebView.NavigationCompleted += browser_NavigationCompleted;
            newWebView.NewWindowRequested += browser_NewWindowRequested;
            newWebView.NavigationStarting += browser_NavigationStarting;
            newWebView.ContainsFullScreenElementChanged += webView_ContainsFullScreenElementChanged;
            newWebView.Navigate(new Uri(url));         
 
            CurrentSelectedTab.Content = newWebView; //Here I set the WebView element as the TabViewItem content, but the WebView is not displayed.
          

        }
```

```
public void GridViewItemTappedCommand_Executed(object obj)
        {
            if (GridViewSelectedItem != null)
            {
                MainPage.SearchWebFromStartPage(GridViewSelectedItem.Url); 
                
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: We can't make sample to reproduce your problem with above code, could you mind share [mcve]?

Comment: @NicoZhu do you believe [this](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/discussions/7414) issue might be the same or it is related to deferred ```Frame``` loading?

Comment: @Herzanet have you attempted to utilize a ```ContentPresenter```